# Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree Does Not Show Menu Correctly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tree, user-controls, leaflet, layer

I am using the menu example with Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree
https://github.com/jjimenezshaw/Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree/blob/master/examples/basic.html, exactly the same as this code, but when I run, it shows different in each browser, as shown in the attached image. Can someone help me? I would like it to show equal to the edge of the attached image in chrome.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqtrc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "L.Control.Layers.Tree.css" crossorigin = "" />
```

I changed to:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "L.Control.Layers.Tree.css" />
```